# Are these concepts okay to show the use of an air purifier?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, designers, graphic-styles, advertising

I'm designing 2 social media posts to show the function/use of indoor air purifiers.
Please see the image. I've sketched the concepts.

[image]

**Left one:** It is an air purifier, which purifies air. So I've shown two cigarettes as chimney and smoke is going away from room, through window. I want to convey a message that bad stuff, like indoor pollutants will stay away from you when you're using the product. I've place the product nearby, and visually shown the smoke is repelled from it (actually this is not actual science, but just a way to convey message).

**Right one:** This is air purifier for office. It is plugged in a socket as shown. Just like we catch a fish, I've shown with a line, it is catching bacteria/virus. I'm also thinking to put 1-2 guys working nearby in a happy mood.

Am I good to go and execute these concepts or they make no sense?

Comment: Request here for clarification of the *purpose* of the designs you're concepting now:
you say social media post to "show the function/use of indoor air purifiers" - do you mean these are ***not*** *advertising* per se, but rather technical illustration exercises? This is a critical point to understand, as you then clearly concept around design directions which are clearly ***not* *technically* accurate at all - is this advertising or technical communications? Info burps? Infomercials??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but no technical diagrams or flying smoke or bacteria presentation will catch the attention of ordinary people. Create an image where the output from the machine is a clean mountain, northern forest or seashore scene and a person sitting in the office has closed his or her eyes and seems to spend just a moment in fresh outdoor air at the same time. The machine outputs its local environment experience.

You can try to input technical facts or something which shows facts after you have caught their attention.

Comment: *where the output from the machine is a clean mountain-, northern forest or seashore scene* didn't get this.

Comment: @Vikas the machine outputs a wide conical beam, the person sits in that beam, the beam is an outdoor scene- fresh, and in good daylight, absolutely not hot,  pleasantly cool like in the mountains or northern Europe. Beyond the beam is the office, a little dark and even smoky, if that happens to be normal where you live. You combine the needed photos.

Comment: This is about 2nd photo. The cigarette idea also sucks?

Comment: @Vikas This was for both of your drawings. The smoke flies to the right. But it's still smoke that exists. Show what you want to claim the user gets. I suggested an experience of fresh air.

Comment: Okay you gave just one idea so I can think in this way? Right?

Comment: @Vikas You can use that idea or reject it, both possiblities are free.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you *ever* want to show "sin industries" - those industries which are notorious for being unhealthy - in an advertisement for something which *is* supposed to be healthy.

i.e. I'd *never* show a cigarette in *any* advertisement unless it was an advertisement *promoting* cigarettes and their usage. Much the same way you'd never show what's is actually being removed from a toilet when selling toilet bowl cleaner.

As for the bacteria.. I get it, but it's too "conceptual" for the general public.. many may not see the ambiguity and wonder why there's a line catching things as if it's some sort of bug catcher.

All purely my *opinion*....

Comment: I entreat you to reply my last message on chat @Scott I know it's too much, but believe me it will be conclusion. I usually take the conversation longer, but in the end it helps a lot. I'll really really appreciate it.

Comment: also the cigarette thing. I've seen people making chimneys from cigarette to show the effect that cigarettes create pollution. @Scott

Comment: I understand *why* you want to use cigarettes. I merely think it's a *bad idea* regardless of any reasoning. People know what "air purifiers" do.. you don't have to show them as if it's a brand new technology.

Comment: Now, according to your comments my both concepts are not completely wrong, they make sense. But below answer by user287001 clearly says it's bad concept.

Comment: Uhm, no. I pretty much stated both concepts are *not ideal* or *could be better*. How you somehow interpreted my answer and comments as being some sort of approval from me, kind of mystifies me.

Comment: I think I'll need to brainstorm again tomorrow. How should I learn the process of brainstorming so that I can think out of the box? Just with experience? Or there are things that I'm not aware of yet?

Answer (score 2):

The use of labels and arrows emphasizes that the metaphor is weak. Explanation is not necessary for an intuitive design.

If you cannot illustrate the process, illustrate the effect. (Sell the sizzle, not the steak.)

Sometimes, anthropomorphic treatment through cartooning works by giving bad-guy human characteristics to the bugs and good-guy characteristics to the air purifier.

The air purifier has a white hat and looks clean and healthy while the bacteria, smoke, and viruses have black hats, stubbled un-shaven and look shabby. Your hero air purifier has a cape and muscles and gets things done.

Logo in the lower right, BTW.

Good luck.

Comment: *illustrate the effect* you mean something like this? https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/different-facial-expressions-round-object_1308-9003.jpg